# socketio issue in internet explorer only

Tags: javascript, socket.io

I have a little chat app that i'm writing with socketio. I have the pieces working in Chrome and Firefox, but Internet Explorer 7-9 all have issues.

I've included the WebSocketMainInsecure.swf and WebSocketMain.swf(not at the same time) both before and after socket.io.js and I get errors.

This is the error, http://screencast.com/t/uUsnyGLV
I can tell it's related to the flash/swf object. This is the way I am including the swf,

```
<object width="0" height="0">
    <param value="resources/lib/socketio/WebSocketMainInsecure.swf">
    <embed src="resources/lib/socketio/WebSocketMainInsecure.swf">
    </embed>
</object>
<script type="text/javascript" src="resources/lib/socketio/socket.io.js"></script>
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?
Thanks!

Edit - after looking at the error in the dev version of socket.io, it looks like an element with id, webSocketFlash, is missing. I tried adding an iframe with that id and also tried adding the id to the object tag. Still having the same error though.

I also have this configuration in nodejs.

```
io.set('transports', [
    'websocket'
    , 'flashsocket'
    , 'htmlfile'
    , 'xhr-polling'
    , 'jsonp-polling'
]);
```

Also I am running nodejs on port 3000 and serving my file with apache on port 80

Comment: I'm no hero in node.js if that what this is but could you remove production settigs? https://github.com/LearnBoost/socket.io/wiki/Configuring-Socket.IO things like browser client minification and log level. Look at How do you set the NODE_ENV flag and set an environment variable to debug when starting your app.

Comment: @HMR I updated the error message using the non minified version

Comment: Not sure how you suppose to set up the socket and how much of the html should be generated dynamically based on your settings but the object doesn't have an ID, later in code it tries to get that (flash) object: document.getElementById("webSocketFlash") and null is returned. Then it tries to invoke a method on that null object which causes the error. Either give your <object a matching id or check out the manual again. Maybe someone with more experience in websocket can give you a hint.

Comment: Does the simple "hello world" work for IE? If it does then it's something in your code but if it doesn't it's something in the setup/settings. http://socket.io/

Comment: Or Maybe this link is more helpful: http://socket.io/#how-to-use Just try the basic and see if that works on IE.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue. I was using `location.origin` to create my socket like this,

```
var socket = io.connect(location.origin + ":3000");
```

but IE doesn't have location.origin. Now I'm using this,

```
var socket = io.connect(location.protocol + "//" + location.host + ":3000");
```